# Uploading text file in MongoDB using Express and Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I want to upload a simple text file and store it in the MongoDB database. How should I go about it? I am able to upload the file through simple HTML code, but not able to store it.

My file.html is something like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h3>Upload File</h3>

<form enctype ="multipart/form-data" action ="/upload" method ="post">

<input type="file" name="userDoc" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload Document" name="submit">

</form>
<br><br><input type=button onClick="location.href='/home'" value='Home'><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Using express or any other method how can I store the uploaded file?

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in the backend by using https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html, you can use this to save the file in a folder in your project.